# chrome extension: storing 'chrome local storage' variable for gmail' multiple loggedin accounts in same browser

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

i am developing a chrome extension that works with gmail. I need to use 'chrome local storage' variable.If i signedin multiple gmail accounts from same browser
, i want to store different values to same variable name for different accounts in different tab. Is there is any way to do this?

Comment: You can use namespaces based on user id.

Comment: @Deliaz How can we use local storage based user id?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). Btw, have you thought about that instead of localStorage?

Comment: @Deliaz, sorry for the mistake , i meant chrome,storage.local itself

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have some unique ID for each user. So then you can put that id to a key name:

```js
var userId1 = 123;
var userId1 = 321;

chrome.storage.local.set('user_' + userId1, {...}); // Set data for User 1
chrome.storage.local.set('user_' + userId2, {...}); // Set data for User 2
```